# How to use "where" argument in a query using graphql and mongodb?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, next.js, strapi

I need a query that looks for specific data, and I created the following query:

```
query GET_RELATORIOS_SLUGW($slug: JSON ) {
  relatorios(where: {slug: $slug}){
     id
    title
    slug
  }
}
```

step by variable:

```
{
  "$slug": "agua"
}
```

but it keeps returning all the data and not just what I'm looking for, I would like some help, to know how to make this query work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slug looks like a string, and your variable syntax wasn't correct.

```
query GET_RELATORIOS_SLUGW($slug: String) {
  relatorios(where: { slug: $slug }) {
    id
    title
    slug
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "slug": "agua"
}
```